# conversion of json to html

Tags: json

I'm new to Java and trying to convert any given json file to an html file without using any external libraries, except GSON to interpret the json structure.

This is an example json file:

```
{
    "doctype": "html",
    "language": "en",
    "head": {
        "meta": {
            "charset": "utf-8",
            "viewport": {
                "width": "device-width",
                "initial-scale": 1
            }
        },
        "title": "Page Not Found"
    },
    "body": {
        "h1": "Page Not Found",
        "p": "Sorry, but the page you were trying to view does not exist."
    }
}
```

And this is the expected output of the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Page Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
        <p>Sorry, but the page you were trying to view does not exist.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the code I have so far:
(The actual conversion method)

```
private static void getJsonData (JsonObject jsonObject) throws IOException {
        jsonObject.keySet().forEach(key ->
        {
            Object value = jsonObject.get(key);

            if (value instanceof JsonObject){
                try {
                    getJsonData((JsonObject) value);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("key " + key + " of value " + value + " is a JsonObject");
            } else if (value instanceof JsonArray){
                try {
                    writeToHtmlFile("<" + key + ">");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("key " + key + " of value " + value + " is a JsonArray");
            } else {
                if (Objects.equals(key, "doctype")) {
                    try {
                        writeToHtmlFile("<!DOCTYPE " + value + ">");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (Objects.equals(key, "language")) {
                    try {
                        writeToHtmlFile("<html lang=" + value + ">");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        writeToHtmlFile("<" + key + ">");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("key " + key + " of value " + value + " is an entry");
            }
            ;
        });
        ;
    }
    ;
```

And this is my current output to an html file, which is obviously incorrect:

```
<!DOCTYPE "html">
<html lang="en">
<charset>
<width>
<initial-scale>
<title>
<h1>
<p>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are not writing HTML elements closing tags which should be wrapping any `JsonObject`:

```
if (value instanceof JsonObject) {
    writeToHtmlFile("<" + key + ">");
    try {
        getJsonData((JsonObject) value);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    writeToHtmlFile("</" + key + ">");
    System.out.println("key " + key + " of value " + value + " is a JsonObject");
}
```

Second you are not writing the literal HTML elements values which should go last if the node is not a `JsonObject`:

```
} else {
    writeToHtmlFile("<" + key + ">");
    writeToHtmlFile(value.toString());
    writeToHtmlFile("</" + key + ">");
}
```

The whole method would then look like the following:

```
public void getJsonData(JsonObject jsonObject) throws IOException {
    jsonObject.keySet().forEach(key ->
    {
        Object value = jsonObject.get(key);
        if (value instanceof JsonObject) {
            try {
                writeToHtmlFile("<" + key + ">");
                getJsonData((JsonObject) value);
                writeToHtmlFile("</" + key + ">");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("key " + key + " of value " + value + " is a JsonObject");
        } else if (value instanceof JsonArray) {
            try {
                writeToHtmlFile("<" + key + ">");
                for (JsonElement next : (JsonArray) value) {
                    getJsonData(next.getAsJsonObject());
                }
                writeToHtmlFile("</" + key + ">");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("key " + key + " of value " + value + " is a JsonArray");
        } else {
            if (Objects.equals(key, "doctype")) {
                try {
                    writeToHtmlFile("<!DOCTYPE " + value + ">");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (Objects.equals(key, "language")) {
                try {
                    writeToHtmlFile("<html lang=" + value + ">");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    writeToHtmlFile("<" + key + ">");
                    writeToHtmlFile(value.toString());
                    writeToHtmlFile("</" + key + ">");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("key " + key + " of value " + value + " is an entry");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct path, this is the output using your code: 
`<!DOCTYPE "html">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta>
<charset>
"utf-8"
</charset>
<viewport>
<width>
"device-width"
</width>
<initial-scale>
1
</initial-scale>
</viewport>
</meta>
<title>
"Page Not Found"
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
"Page Not Found"
</h1>
<p>
"Sorry, but the page you were trying to view does not exist."
</p>
</body>`
However, this still isn't entirely correct and I don't know how to deal with nested objects. JsonArrays should also be iterated over and nested accordingly..

Comment: I pointed out the two main issues and iterating over the `JsonArray`
 is simply a matter of following the same reasoning. Indeed, the output is not entirely correct as for example `meta` tags needs special processing and cannot be considered as nested HTML elements.